# 20 amp circuit for lighting

Tags: electrical

San Bernardino Ca. area. 20 amp circuit #12 wire, Can I use this circuit for Lighting? On this circuit 5  20 amp outlets and 6 LED fixtures 50 watts each. One outlet will be used for a refrigerator.

Comment: Where in the house are these outlets located?  Also, do you already have your two 20A kitchen small appliance branch circuits covered?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Although I'd watch what you use with these receptacles as you could easily trip the breaker with the refrigerator on there too.

Also, I doubt those LED lights are 50W. They're probably much lower unless each fixture is like a chandelier with multiple bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

If this is one of your 2 20A small appliance circuits the lighting should not be on it NEC handbook exhibit 210.28.
I think it is always a bad idea to have a refrigerator on a small appliance circuit but it is allowed by code.
If this is in addition to the 2 small appliance branch circuits for the kitchen countertop area it is legal.

Comment: This is a dedicated  20 amp circuit in garage for 1 refrigerator and 5 LED light fixtures @ 60 watts each. including 5 outlets.

Comment: You will need GFCI protection in the garage per NEC 210.8(2) all outlets now require GFCI including the Refrigerator.

Comment: Is it ok to have one GFCI to protect circuit (outlets) or GFCI at each outlet? Lighting need GFCI?

Comment: Just the outlets need the GFCI one at the first outlet can protect the string the lights dont require GFCI unless they have a outlet in the fixture.